# Change pivot point without moving the current position?

Tags: animation

So I animated some objects rotating, and the pivot point is on top. but now I want to move the pivot point to the side a bit while still being on top, but the object positions are already animated. help please?

Comment: Yes, that solved my question

Comment: These are very different questions, and people who are at a beginner lever trying to move the pivot point and get thrown on the other question which involves constraints and animation, might find it hard to get